# Migrate all contacts from Outlook 2013 to Outlook on the web

Tags: outlook-on-the-web

My company is dropping desktop versions of Microsoft Office in favour of online  equivalents. Our sysadmin has migrated mail messages but not contacts. My findings so far:

- *.pst format: Outlook on the web doesn't seem to support it.
- Exporting to CSV: exporting the top-level "Contacts" item generates an empty file (with just headers). Exporting each individual item seems to work but I'd need to repeat it several dozen times.
- Official documentation and YouTube videos assume that contacts must be imported in desktop app and will magically show up on the web. I presume that only happens if you buy the appropriate licence.
- The commercial application that buys ads in Google searches appears to be some kind of scam.

Is there a way to migrate all contacts at once from Outlook 2013 to Outlook on the web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually reached the conclusion that the only way is to use CSV and painfully go several dozen times through the export/import cycle.